# nUnit Assert.That(method,Throws.Exception) not catching exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, exception

Can someone tell me why this unit test that checks for exceptions fails?  Obviously my real test is checking other code but I'm using Int32.Parse to show the issue.

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    Assert.That(Int32.Parse("abc"), Throws.Exception.TypeOf<FormatException>());
}
```

The test fails, giving this error.  Obviously I'm trying to test for this exception and I think I'm missing something in my syntax.

```
Error   1   TestCase '.MyTest'
failed: System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
```

based on the documentation at [Throws Constraint (NUnit 2.5)](http://nunit.net/index.php?p=throwsConstraint&r=2.5.3)

Comment: Also you can do this: `Assert.Throws<FormatException>(() => Int32.Parse("abc"));`

Comment: I was trying to stick with the Assert.That style for this project. I'm not as attached to it as I once I was though.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Assert.That(() => Int32.Parse("abc"), Throws.Exception.TypeOf<FormatException>());
```

Basically you need to pass a delegate to `Assert.That`, just like the documentation in your link states (note that I've used a lambda expression here, but it should be the same).

Comment: ah I had to make in an anonymous delegate... I see that in the documentation now, it just wasn't super clear.  Thanks!

Comment: Incase someone runs into the fact that their anonymous function returns void, you'll need to do something like: `Assert.That(new Action(() => VoidReturningMethod("abc")), Throws.Exception.TypeOf<FormatException>());`

Comment: Thanks @MartinNeal that helped me on the right path, but for me it complained that it had to be a TestDelegate, so I had to do: `new TestDelegate(() => AddBlockingTaskToBox())` or

Answer (score 9):

What test runner are you using? Not all of them work correctly with the exception assertions.

You may have better luck using `[ExpectedException (typeof(FormatException))]` or even `Assert.Throws<FormatException> (() => Int32.Parse("abc"));`

Comment: I was using TDD.net and nUnit gui.  Your fix worked, but I want to use the fluent syntax.  I gave you a point though for the help!

Comment: I know this is an old answer that was right at that moment.  But for now and future reference, `ExpectedException` attribute is deprecated on NUnit 3.0: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Breaking-Changes